# What is the modern equivalent of "scoundrel"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Someone who deliberately sets someone up. Some of whose actions can be described as "a dick move." Someone who habitually commits base acts that hurt other people. Someone whom one would not trust if one knew them.

*Scoundrel* no longer has the same ring it did a century ago.

*Asshole* is way too general a term.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63877/discussion-on-question-by-ricky-what-is-the-modern-equivalent-of-scoundrel).

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest several adjectives that might modify a person of this sort: nasty, sadistic, mean-spirited. Your use of "a dick move" as an example would make "dickhead" a natural, if vulgar choice.

Comment: The principle trait of a scoundrel is betraying people's trust habitually. A "dickhead" is something else entirely. A "dick move" would be, say, you recommending a person as a potential valuable employee, with them then taking your job. Spreading ugly rumors about you behind you back would also qualify as a "dick move." Thus "nasty," "sadistic," "mean-spirited" do not quite cut it. One can be nasty without being a scoundrel; one can be sadistic while remaining an honest person; and one can be mean-spirited yet morally okay.

Answer (score 1):

***creep*** or ***slime-ball***

[Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/scoundrel) lists **creep** as a synonym for scoundrel.  But it lists a lot of words as a synonym for scoundrel.  Why do I pick creep?

In the discussion which has been moved to chat, the OP says, disagreeing with the suggestion of backstabber:

> A person who steals an old lady's savings by hacking into her account
>   is not a backstabber, but certainly a scoundrel, and the act can
>   certainly be classified as a "dick move".

Such a person evokes the same shudder as something slimy that has crept out from under a rock.  (My apologies to everything that lives under a rock.) But this is ELU, and why should anyone believe what **I** say?  So here are definitions:

**creep**, from [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/creep)

> A detestable person.
>
> ‘I thought he was a nasty little creep’

As for **slime-ball**, which I prefer: [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/slimeball):

> A repulsive or despicable person

Comment: +1 for trying. I'd give you a +100 if I could. I'm terribly sorry we can't have a civilized discussion on the subject here. The matter is very intriguing and would have benefited and/or gratified lots of people for whom language is a passion.